# What security measures does Steam use to prevent games from being copied?

Tags: file-access

What is preventing anyone from copying a game file from an app like Steam and sending it to others? Is there a measure to make it unplayable on devices where it wasn't purchased?

Comment: Are you asking about if a game in particular that was downloaded from Steam takes measures to prevent itself from being run on a machine other than the one it was downloaded to, or if Steam itself does something to prevent games from being copied and run on other machines? It's my understanding that games downloaded on Steam *can* get Steam to do something about it, but that some games won't necessarily have that. For example, have you considered launching an app from `SteamLibrary\steamapps\common` directly while not being logged into Steam to see what it does for a given game?